# Is it true that diagonal walls divide Alien more than horizontal and vertical walls?

Tags: factorio

In a multiplayer game, a friend suggested me to set up diagonal walls instead of vertical and horizontal ones.

He was telling me that enemies will attack at the same point on vertical / horizontal walls and, unlike diagonal structured walls, they will be more likely to split up and attack different points, so letting you more time to defend.

Is it true?

Comment: I can't confirm, but now that I think about it, I think the diagonal walls do distract them longer.

Comment: In my experience, the enemies tend to get 'stuck' on corners a lot, trying to path around it instead of just attack, which also leads to more time for defending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the lack of answer, I'll share what I've found.

By the time, I tried both ways to build walls and I noticed that **Aliens will be more sparsed in face of diagonal walls**.

So this is my answer until someone can prove the contrary or add valuable informations on the subject.

Even if it's not directly related, I would add to this a small recommendation about diagonal walls. In fact, I don't use them anymore because it's was painful in mid and late game to use blueprint and enlarge the base when everything else was horizontal. So I suggest to build horizontal walls for a better scalability even if Alien are "stronger".